# Are there any tools to convert legacy VML to SVG?

Tags: asp.net, svg, vml

Just wondering if anybody has come across a tool or anything to make the process easier of converting VML to SVG or some other modern format (Silverlight, flash).

I'm dealing with some legacy VML browser renderings and I'd like to make it cross browser compatible.  Right now the vml is being generated on the server side.

Would also be helpful if there was a chart to map VML markup to SVG, in table format as a cheat sheet or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vector Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vectorconverter/) claims to convert between SVG and VML, among other formats.