# Convert jQuery SVG to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg

I am generating SVG object using jQuery SVG plug-in. The problem is how can I convert it into image in my script.

My script is following:

```
<html>
<head>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script>                
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $("#draw").click(function(){
     $('#svg_container').svg();
     svg = $('#svg_container').svg('get');
     svg.clear(true);
     svg.circle(200, 220, 150, {fill: "red", stroke: "blue", strokeWidth: 5});
     alert(svg.toSVG()); //this prints svg source of the generated image, i.e. circle
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="svg_container" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 400px; height: 400px; border: thin solid #4297D7;"></div>
<button id="draw">Draw</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php/4809562#4809562) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/conversion-of-svg-to-jpeg/3976034#3976034) but without success.

Could you please show me how to convert this svg into any type of image?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The problem is solved and I have posted the solution as an answer, check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827764/convert-jquery-svg-to-image/4836882#4836882).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert SVG to image (JPEG, PNG, etc.)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975499/convert-svg-to-image-jpeg-png-etc)

Answer (score -6, accepted):

I have finally solved the problem of converting SVG to image file. Here is the solution, if anybody is interested in:

```
<html>
<head>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.min.js"></script>                
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.svg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbcolor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    function q(k){
       var qs = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var t = qs.split("&");
       for (i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
        kv = t[i].split("=");
            if (kv[0] == k) return unescape(kv[1]).replace('+',' ');
       }
       return null;
    }

    var context;
    function bodyonload() {
       if (typeof(FlashCanvas) != 'undefined') context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext;
       var qUrl = q('url'); if (qUrl != null && qUrl != '') { r(); canvg('canvas', qUrl); }
       var qSvg = q('svg'); if (qSvg != null && qSvg != '') { r(); canvg('canvas', qSvg); }
    }

    function render() {
       var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
       c.width = 400;
       c.height = 500;
       if (context) c.getContext = context;
       canvg(c, document.getElementById('svg').value);
       var svg_content = c.toDataURL();
       $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"svg.php",
                 data: ({
                      svg_content: svg_content
                 }),
                 timeout: 30000, //30 sec.                            
       });
    }   

    function r() {
        var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
        c.width = '1000'; //change it to the width of your image
        c.height = '600'; //change it to the height of your image
        if (context) c.getContext = context;
    }

    $("#save").click(function(){
        render();
    });

    $("#draw").click(function(){
        $('#svg_container').svg();
        svg = $('#svg_container').svg('get');
        svg.clear(true);
        svg.circle(200, 220, 150, {fill: "red", stroke: "blue", strokeWidth: 5});
        $("#svg").val(svg.toSVG());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="svg" rows="5" cols="50" style="visibility: hidden;"></textarea><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000px" height="600px"></canvas>
<div id="svg_container" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 100px; width: 400px; height: 400px; border: thin solid #4297D7;"></div>
<button id="draw" style="position: absolute; top:400px; left: 500px;">Draw</button>
<button id="save" style="position: absolute; top:400px; left: 550px;">Save</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The content of svg.php is following:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['svg_content'])){
     $imageData=$_POST['svg_content'];
     $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
     $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
     $fp = fopen('test.png', 'wb' );
     fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
     fclose( $fp );
}
?>
```

You can download jQuery library (jquery-latest.min.js) from jQuery official [web site](http://jquery.com/) and jQuery SVG library from [here](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html) .

Hope this will help to many of you who are looking toward converting SVG to image right from your program.

Best,

Bakhtiyor

Comment: i don't see this generating any image

Comment: @fazo. It generates test.png in the current folder.

Comment: yes, what are it contents? because i don't see that in svg.php you are generating any png

Comment: @fazo. It's content is SVG tags.

Comment: so.. you are 'converting' SVG to SVG then?

Comment: @fazo. Call it as you like but I was looking forward to store the result of grammatically generated SVG to file. And by the way it is one of the hot topics for SVG, I think.

Comment: the point is, you are generating 'test.png' in svg.php but it doesn't have anything to do with png.

Comment: @fazo. Do you have any solution for my problem? If so, please be so kind to post it as an answer.

Comment: problem is, you was asking for a converter from SVG to and image, and accepted your 'solution' which is not doing what you was asking for. why are you lying that you are writing 'test.png' when it has nothing to do with png or any other image format

Comment: @fazo. Final goal was to convert (or to save) SVG into any image format. I have PNG image format as a result of the script and the goal is achieved.

Comment: can you view it with image Viewer? no. Writing some data to a file and naming it data.png doesn't make it a png file

Comment: This is one of the silliest answers I've seen on this site. You need to pay attention to what fazo is saying....

Comment: This is not an anwser ... You need to convert your data to an image format before saving it to a filename whose extension is named after this format. You can't convert wav to mp3 by just renaming a file.

Answer (score 6):

This seams to be very hard to do.

I found this project that attempts to do this:

http://www.svgopen.org/2010/papers/62-From_SVG_to_Canvas_and_Back/index.html

I also found one project that tried to build a SVG renderer for Canvas but it was far from complete.

They did use a solution to go by the server and have the SVG rendered to PNG there, that might be the only really working solution right now.