# php5: convert svg to png base64 encoded

Tags: php, svg, png, base64

how can i convert a svg string

```
<svg>....<path>...</path>...</svg>
```

to a png base64 encoded string / file in php?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php) is an even closer match I think.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function

```php
function svgToBase64 ($filepath){  

    if (file_exists($filepath)){

        $filetype = pathinfo($filepath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

        if ($filetype==='svg'){
            $filetype .= '+xml';
        }

        $get_img = file_get_contents($filepath);
        return 'data:image/' . $filetype . ';base64,' . base64_encode($get_img );
    }
}
```