# Convert SVG to an image (png, jpg)

Tags: image, svg

Hey i'm encountering the following problem.
I want to convert an dinamically generated (through php) SVG image to an image so a user can rightclick and "save image .."

at the moment the image is displayed as an svg for example
like this:

```
<embed id="image_wuerfel" classid="image/svg+xml" 
src="/svg/models.php?s=c&w=5&h=5&l=5&m=1&desc=1&wh=250&wl=250" 
type="image/svg+xml" width="250" height="250">
</embed>
```

it sends a GET - Request to the models.php, where the SVG image is generated and will be returned.

Is there something like a JS library or something, that converts this into an image file?

Comment: what about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You could use Imagick php class from ImageMagick.