# HTML SVG download image

Tags: html, svg

I am planning a web-page where images will be generated online. 
Now it's about to be decided whether I want to use SVG or images generated by an backend script.
Download is an essential feature.
Is there a way to download an html - svg generated object as a PNG/JPG/... ?

Comment: There are ways to convert SVG to PNG using PHP and then you can use whatever technique you like for the download.

See these posts RE conversion:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289686/rendering-an-svg-file-to-a-png-or-jpeg-in-php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php

Comment: thanks, that should be a good solution. however, there's no javascript class that could do it on the browserside?

Comment: Yes actually, I hadn't thought of that. Not exactly a class but a simple way to do it would be render the svg to a canvas (visible or not) and export the canvas as a data URI.