# convert svg to cmyk using php or any command or using tcpdf

Tags: php, svg, tcpdf, cmyk

I am inserting svg image into pdf using `tcpdf`. And `tcpdf` writes pdf in `rgb` using this command

```
$pdf->ImageSVG
```

But i want to convert it to `cmyk`. So i thought i have 2 way to do this,

**1)convert svg to cmyk**

For this i tried this command

```
shell_exec("convert {$svgPath} -profile 'Canon_iPF_5000_-_iPF_8000_-_iPF_9000.icc' {$svgoppath}");
```

But not working

**2)convert pdf to cmyk while writing svg**

I tried to find in google regarding this, but no proper documentation of `tcpdf` to force write pdf in `cmyk`

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/color.html#ColorProfileElement

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for getting through my situation, svg is generating autoamtic, so what code should i have to append or insert or update in svg? i have many elements in svg like `<g transform="translate(1127.57 398.53)">
  <text font-family="Impact" font-size="25" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" ><tspan x="-100" y="5.61" fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)">Type Text Here</tspan></text>
 </g>` which has `fill` property in `rgb`.

Comment: ok thanks @Kaiido appreciate.

Comment: Does the image need to be an SVG? If this is not necessary then you could use ImageMagick to change it to another format (example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289686/rendering-an-svg-file-to-a-png-or-jpeg-in-php) and then user ImageMagick again the change the image's colourspace using `transformImageColorspace`.

Comment: @Michael i installed imagick on server and i am getting error here https://www.printhubpro.co.uk/ajax/svgtest

Comment: My suggestion was to convert the SVG to another format before changing its colourspace which you do not appear to be doing.

Comment: @Michael problem is i need to keep vector image, after converting to any other it converted to grey-scale

Comment: @Michael `PDF_load_iccprofile` is it usefull? i am not getting any example of this function even.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP way to convert to colorspace is to use  iMagick's [setimagecolorspace](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php) which is the equivalent to the `exec(convert....`. If option 1) doesn't work, chances are `setimagecolorspace` will fail too.

Ensure that [imagemagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php) library & utilities are installed on server, else you'd be spending hours debugging code that isn't broken.

Comment: i have installed imagick on server and trying this code also, `$image=Config::get('constants.paths.uploads.images.base')."/test.svg";
     $image2=Config::get('constants.paths.uploads.images.base')."/test_new.svg";
  $IMagick = new IMagick();
  $IMagick->clear();
  $IMagick->readImage($image); 
  $icc_cmyk = ltrim(Config::get('constants.paths.uploads.images.base').'/1.icc',"/");
  $IMagick->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk); 
  //unset($icc_cmyk); 
  $IMagick->transformImageColorspace(12);
  $IMagick->writeImage ($image2);` but getting error `ColorspaceColorProfileMismatch `icc' `

Comment: yes great no error now, but issue is, svg is not readable now, it only shows codes like this, http://printhubpro.co.uk/images/test_new.svg and original is here http://printhubpro.co.uk/images/test.svg

Comment: Are you trying to change the `fill` RGB to CMYK color? That's not possible with iMagick. The only app I am aware of is Scribus, where you can export [SVG to PDF CMYK](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_set_CMYK_color_on_a_design_for_printing)

Comment: is ther any other way to do with php?

Comment: Have you tried using ghostscript to convert a RGB to CMYK PDF? It is a tall order to insert cmyk into svg, then update internals of tcpdf to read cmyk.

Comment: but i dont know how to use it in laravel