# Base64 Image will not scale down using any common methods

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui, base64

I am using KendoUI's diagram feature, and want to export the resulting construct to display as a thumbnail.

I am exporting the image, which is in Base64 format. This is then saved.

This data is then loaded into a div, and needs to be scaled to fit the div. However, I have tried absolutely every common technique to scale the image down, but it simply will not.

Currently I have something like this. It is a piece of html which is being used as a template for a keno list. There may be something here which is causing the issue, but I have failed to find it if there is.

```
<div id="thumbnailContainer" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
   <img id="thumbnail" src="#:imageData#" style="(every technique under the 
   sun tried)"
</div>
```

where the "#:imageData# corresponds to someBase64 image data (which correctly displays and loads otherwise)

Techniques tried:

- Background-size
- Setting background of container instead
- Adjusting height and width of img

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqggd8dh/)

Comment: Did you try to set the width and height of the container to the size you want for the image?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example for us to be able to help.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Can't see where I edit my question, but here is an existing JSFiddle I amended to show the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kqggd8dh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention it's an SVG, not just some image. SVG is "special" when it comes to sizing. It's probably a good idea not to base64 for SVG since it doesn't save space or gain you anything. The trick is to add `viewBox="0 0 W H"` to the `<svg>` tag. In your case `viewBox='0 0 2400 1200'` seems to work well. If you insist on base64 you need to add it before you convert it.

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/kqggd8dh/1/)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, it was driving me mad, I didn't expect SVG to make a difference. To save me time, do you know if using PDF instead would allow the scaling to work?

Comment: Oh no. PDF probably wouldn't even display as image. If you only want to show a thumbnail, your best bet is to render that svg to image. Take at look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10289762/559079). It uses PHP and ImageMagick

Comment: Cheers, I'm not familiar with rendering various imaging formats inside html as you can probably tell. I will have a look, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

try doing this in your code

```
<img id="thumbnail" src="'data:image/png;base64,' + your_base64_string" style="width:50px;height:250px">
```

this should work. If its not working then you may have problem with your other css.

Comment: I now have a JSFiddle example showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/kqggd8dh/
If you do as you have suggested, it appears to just crop the image instead of scale it

Comment: using the css **transform: scale(0.5, 0.5)** I am able to do now