# PHP Library to Convert HTML containg SVGs to PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, svg, html2pdf

Is there any library or combination of Libraries I can use to Generate PDF from HTML containing SVGs.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

- [Convert SVG image to PNG with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4809194/1393862)
- [Use PHP PDF library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)
- To add a photo use [`PDF_load_image`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdf-load-image.php)

Answer (score 0):

Using TCPDF
[PHP Code](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.phps) 
[PHP Code Execution](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_058.pdf)