# Raphael.js free transform image and save

Tags: service, web, save, raphael, transform

I have a project that will require free transforming an object like this ( http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/ ) except with an image (png). After the image is manipulated, I will then need to send the image to a web service using AJAX Post. Can anyone help with an example?

Comment: What about [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php)?

Answer (score 0):

Raphael is not designed for images processing, really. I would suggest that you store the parameters the user chooses (the rotation, scale, etc.) and then apply them to the original image in plain javascript. If you stick to affine transformations, it would suffice to store the positions of the four corners of the image and apply, e.g., bilinear interpolation. Or even better: send the parameters and the image back to the server and do it there.