# Saving SVG as PNG

Tags: php, javascript, html, canvas, svg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert SVG image to PNG with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php)

I have a bunch of `SVG` text that's dynamic that I need to save as a PNG.  I can't use `canvg` because it doesn't support paths (I have arced text).  I'd like to avoid having to install anything server side, but if there's a native PHP function, then I can work with that.  What're my options for getting what I need done?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php and maybe this: http://code.google.com/p/phpsvg/

Comment: `GD` can't, `ImageMagick` can.

Comment: It's always a good idea to use [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/) on your server for such purposes. Some hosters even have pre-installed.

Comment: try apache's batick.it's java based, but I managed to call it through php's exec function to save a svg to png