# RaphaelJS SVG to PNG

Tags: javascript, svg, png, raphael

I am currently struggling to convert SVG and its contents to a png using PHP. I am using raphaeljs to draw shapes onto an image and then i covert the shapes and image to a SVG. I have the svg tag and the fills etc but i need to somehow convert this into a PNG.

If anyone could share some code then that would be great.

Im at this current point in my code:

```
<script>
var svg = paper[<?=$vehicletype['vehicletypeid']?>].toSVG();
console.log(svg);
</script>
```

Any solution would be appreciated. It needs to work in IE8 so thats why im not using canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do, you need to look into using the [ImageMagick library](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and its [php extensions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php#php) such as  iMagick.  A lot of hosting providers either already have it built in or allow you to add the extension manually.  This library handles a myriad of different image manipulation operations including converting files types to different types. This answer here, [Convert SVG image to PNG with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4809194/2236808), also gives nice breakdown of how you would actually use this for your project.  Hope this helps.