# PHP split font + Get char width

Tags: php, svg, fonts, ascii

I am trying to automate separating fonts or another project, but I just can't find the answer. What I mean by separate is to save each character with an ascii value from 32 to 126 into multiple svg files (preferrably convert text to path). My question is,how do I generate multiple svg files, each containing a specific character from a specific (ttf) font.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote https://github.com/Pomax/PHP-Font-Parser for this quite a while ago; the fonttest.php generates JSON, but if you actually run the code you'll see that the JSON also contains [the SVG path outline](https://github.com/Pomax/PHP-Font-Parser/blob/master/Font%20parser/OTF%20data/Glyph%20classes/glyph.php#L38-L57), which you can drop into an SVG skeleton with a `<path d="..."/>` element, and a viewbox set up to match the dimensions that the glyph's JSON provides.

Comment: What version of PHP is this intended for? My Wamp server (PHP 5.6) seems to have many errors!

Comment: whatever version we had 4 years ago. 5.2?

Comment: if you file whatever you find, I can have a look at making them less 5.6-warny (I just tried to run it with 5.6, works fine, just with a ton of PHP strict warnings)

Answer (score 0):

My code below will create an image from a letter using a given font. Follow that to get your image, then [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php) for how to cenvert it to SVG..

```
    // Create an image from the letter "A" using a certain font at 12 points
    $image = createTextImage("A", "12", "font.ttf");

    /**
    * Make an image of text
    * @param type $text
    * @param type $size
    * @param type $color
    * @param type $font
    */
   function createTextImage($text, $font_size, $font_file){

          // Make sure font file exists
          if(!file_exists($font_file)) throw new Exception("Font file does not exist: {$font_file}");         

          // Retrieve bounding box:
          $type_space = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font_file, $text);

          // Determine image width and height, 10 pixels are added for 5 pixels padding:
          $image_width = abs($type_space[4] - $type_space[0]) + 10;
          $image_height = abs($type_space[5] - $type_space[1]) + 10;
          $line_height = getLineHeight($font_size, $font_file) +10;

          // Create image:
          $image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_width, $image_height);

          // Allocate text and background colors (RGB format):
          $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 250, 250, 250);

          // Fill with transparent background
          imagealphablending($image, false);
          imagesavealpha($image, true);
          $transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
          imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);

          // Fix starting x and y coordinates for the text:
          $x = 5; // Padding of 5 pixels.
          $y = $line_height - 5; // So that the text is vertically centered.

          // Add TrueType text to image:
          imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font_file, $text);

          // Save the image to a temp png file to use in our constructor
          $tmpname = tempnam('/tmp', 'IMG');

          // Generate and save image
          imagepng($image, $tmpname, 9);

          return $tmpname;
   }

   /**
   * Returns the line height based on the font and font size
   * @param type $fontSize
   * @param type $fontFace
   */
  function getLineHeight($fontSize, $fontFace){
    // Arbitrary text is drawn, can't be blank or just a space
    $type_space = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $fontFace, "Robert is awesome!");
    $line_height = abs($type_space[5] - $type_space[1]);
    return $line_height;
  }
```

Comment: this is not really a sensible approach, given that glyphs inside fonts are already vector graphics, so rasterizing and then trying to turn the bitmap back into vectors is a twice-lossy conversion. You can just directly extract the glyph outlines and drop them in an SVG `<path>` element, done.