# How do you remove all javascript from an SVG file?

Tags: javascript, svg, xss, code-injection

We're planning on allowing users to upload SVG files and icons. The problem is that SVG files can contain JavaScript, and are thus very vulnerable for injection attacks.

```
<svg 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="780" height="550" 
onload="(function(){ alert('doing something nasty') })()">
```

would execute this code when the svg file is used.

I found this [nice library to manage SVG files](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svgo). This helps in being able to remove attributes like onEVENT='someJs()' ; but that's still not going to help me sleep at night.

So how could one completely sweep an SVG file of JS code in a clever way?

Comment: Load the SVG via an <img> tag or as a background-image then no javascript will run.

Comment: Host the svg on a subdomain and use a content-policy that prevents JavaScript.

Comment: Convert the image to png on upload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://digi.ninja/blog/svg_xss.php details this rather well.

It states:

1. Direct view - **vulnerable** - The file is linked to directly.
2. Direct view with content-disposition: attachment - **not vulnerable** - Headers are sent to force the file to be downloaded.
3. Direct view with CSP - **not vulnerable** - The Content Security Policy is set to disallow inline JavaScript.
4. Image Tags - **not vulnerable** - The SVG is referenced through image tags which prevent scripts.
5. Tags With CSP - **not vulnerable** - Image tags and the same CSP as above for double protection.
6. Sanitised through Inkscape - **vulnerable** - This is a direct view but the file has been processed by the following command:

   ```
   inkscape --file="xss.svg" --verb="FileVacuum" --export-plain-svg="sanitised.svg"
   ```

( It was expected that this would remove the JavaScript but it did not. )

7. Image in an iframe - **vulnerable** - The SVG is loaded as the source for the iframe with no special attributes set.
8. Image in a sandboxed iframe - **not vulnerable** - The SVG is loaded as the source for the iframe but the sandbox attribute is set to
   block scripts.

---

You can also just export to a different filetype that doesn't have this issue. An example using Inkscape's CLI on Linux:

inkscape --export-type="png" /home/x/Pictures/example.svg

https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Using_the_Command_Line has more information under "Export files".

---

Edit: the following projects can actually strip JavaScript out:

- https://github.com/jakearchibald/svgomg , which describes itself as "SVGO's Missing GUI".
- SVGO: https://github.com/svg/svgo , in their README says "SVG Optimizer is a Node.js-based tool for optimizing SVG vector graphics files."

Comment: Note to the visitor: one issue with (3) is that the policy "self" doesn't allow inline styles (whether `<style>` or `@style`). See https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-csp/issues/45 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1262842 for discussions of those issues.