# How to Convert SVG Images to PNG without Loosing Dimensions Using PHP

Tags: php, svg, type-conversion

I tried to convert a SVG image to PNG using [meyfa/php-svg](https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg) PHP Library.

Here is the code

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use SVG\SVG;

$image = SVG::fromFile('new.svg');

$doc = $image->getDocument();

$rasterImage = $image->toRasterImage(1024,1024);

imagepng($rasterImage,'output.png');

?>
```

This is the converted png output
[image: QR coutput]

Here is the original svg
[image: Original svg rendering]

svg file : h[ttps://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDNOzoU9aG2sDj-No_v-psjMiQ1wVPEA/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jDNOzoU9aG2sDj-No_v-psjMiQ1wVPEA/view?usp=sharing)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px"
    y="0px" viewBox="0 0 320.8 417.7" xml:space="preserve" style="enable-background: new 0 0 320.8 417.7" width="1024"
    height="720">
    <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
        @import url('https://online-qr-generator.com/themes/altum/assets/fonts/style.css?family=GT-Walsheim-Pro');

        .st1 {
            font-family: 'GT-Walsheim-Pro';
        }

        .st2 {
            font-size: 42px;
        }

        .black-area {
            fill: #000000;
        }

        .white-area {
            fill: #ffffff;
        }

        .text-color {
            fill: #FFF;
        }
        ]]>
    </style>
    <g>
        <path class="black-area"
            d="M320.8,14.9C320.8,4,317.2,0,306.9,0H13.6C4.6,0,2.3,1.9,0,10.5v396.3c0.5,5.7,2.8,9.9,9,11h302.4c3.6-1,7-2.3,8.3-6.3   c0.9-2.9,1.2-5.9,1.1-8.8v-49.3C320.8,240.5,320.8,127.7,320.8,14.9z M307.5,303.6c0,4.1-0.9,5.1-5.1,5.1   c-94.8-0.1-189.7-0.1-284.5,0c-4.1,0-5.1-0.9-5.1-5.1c0.2-47.5,0.1-94.9,0.1-142.4c0-47.6,0.1-95.3-0.1-142.9   c0-4.1,0.9-5.1,5.1-5.1c94.8,0.1,189.7,0.1,284.5,0c4.1,0,5.1,0.9,5.1,5.1C307.4,113.5,307.4,208.5,307.5,303.6z" />
        <path class="white-area"
            d="M307.5,303.6c0,4.1-0.9,5.1-5.1,5.1c-94.8-0.1-189.7-0.1-284.5,0c-4.1,0-5.1-0.9-5.1-5.1   c0.2-47.5,0.1-94.9,0.1-142.4c0-47.6,0.1-95.3-0.1-142.9c0-4.1,0.9-5.1,5.1-5.1c94.8,0.1,189.7,0.1,284.5,0c4.1,0,5.1,0.9,5.1,5.1   C307.4,113.5,307.4,208.5,307.5,303.6z" />
        <text x="55" y="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 105.65 380.0901)" class="st1 st2 text-color"
            style="text-anchor: middle">Scan me!</text>
    </g>
    <g>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="linear">
                <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color: GLC1;" />
                <stop offset="70%" style="stop-color: GLC2;" />


            </linearGradient>

        </defs>
        <defs>
            <radialGradient id="radial">
                <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color: GRC1" />
                <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color: GRC2" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="linear-b">
                <stop offset="30%" style="stop-color: GLCB1;" />
                <stop offset="70%" style="stop-color: GLCB2;" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <defs>
            <radialGradient id="radial-b">
                <stop offset="10%" style="stop-color: GRCB1" />
                <stop offset="90%" style="stop-color: GRCB2" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
    </g>
    <image
        xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
        x="35" y="30" width="250" height="250" />
</svg>
```

How can i convert that svg image to png with **correct dimensions?**

Comment: Duplicate question! [Convert SVG image to PNG with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php)

Comment: I tried several ways, but I can't find any that will convert an SVG to PNG, without the use of Imagick.

Comment: @NebojsaNebojsa, you linked a question from 12 years ago.  Surely anyone could expect things to have changed by then.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert SVG image to PNG with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809194/convert-svg-image-to-png-with-php)

Comment: The svg doesn't have the dimensions of 1024x1024 (it's 1024x720). Actually the QR svg is pretty complicated (too much whitespace, using an external custom font that won't be rendered etc) In your case you might rather choose a **better QR generator** that's creating png directly.  There's definitely no shortage of libraries generating QR codes serverside (e.g php) or via javaScript.

Comment: That [package](https://github.com/meyfa/php-svg) does not handle the transforms correctly, so you will not be able to get it to work. The SVG is unnecessarily complex with the nested base64 encoded SVG image for the QR code, and multiple transforms. What is the reason for wanting to use this SVG as the source, as opposed to generating with gd?