# Convert VML to PDF

Tags: php, javascript, vml

Is there a way to convert a VML (SVG on IE browsers) formats to PDF format with PHP or JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

No such library exists (to my knowledge) in JavaScript or PHP, nor (in fact) in any language. Your easiest path would likely be to [convert VML to SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473773/are-there-any-tools-to-convert-legacy-vml-to-svg) commands, and then [convert SVG to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=SVG+to+PDF).