# Convert VML code into SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, vml

I need to convert one huge application that contains lots of VML code. This VML code need to be converted into SVG in order to run smoothly on IE10.

I have seen many libraries that convert SVG into VML, but not the opposite. 
So, Does anybody has come across either a tool or a library that make this process?

I was expecting to not change VML code manually, maybe something that can interpret the VML and convert into SVG on the fly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any tools to convert legacy VML to SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473773/are-there-any-tools-to-convert-legacy-vml-to-svg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question: [Are there any tools to convert legacy VML to SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473773/are-there-any-tools-to-convert-legacy-vml-to-svg) and the answer seems to be a tool called [Vector Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vectorconverter/)